# How to leave from 4 networks out of 5 networks

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I joined on the following networks with blind interest.

1. Stack Overflow.
2. Server Fault.
3. Puzzling.
4. Database Administrator.
5. Game Development.

Now I want to leave from all networks, expect Stack Overflow.

I googled about *exit* from a network. It shows me the *Delete Profile* option.

Does *Delete Profile* remove me from all networks or only the corresponding network?

**Updates:**

I got what I need....

*Delete Profile* will delete an individual account..!

[image: I got what I need....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete your account on one site independently of all other accounts.

So if you want to delete all but your Stack Overflow account you can delete those without affecting the Stack Overflow one, but you will have to delete each one in turn.

Just click on the "Delete Profile" link on the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab on your profile page.